# Serialize session content for Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, session, serialization

I wish to serialize some session content for an Ajax request. Something similar to this:

```
var data = $.session("data").serialize();
```

It is for a standard [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "script.php",
   data: data,
   success: function() {
     ...
   }
});
```

The [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) only operates on form elements, so I am looking for something similar. Something that handles an array in a form representing a SESSION data array.

Does that exist or do I have to use a foreach loop to serialize the session content in a POST-friendly string manually?

Comment: What does `$.session("data")` refer to? Are you using a plugin and browser-side `sessionStorage`? If it's [jQuery-Session-Plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin/blob/master/jquery.session.js), I don't know that `$.session().serialize()` will do anything, unless `$.session('data')` was itself an object/array to serialize as it is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main real reason to use the serialize function on data like that is when it originates from several sources - such as a form element containing many input fields.  One serialize command on the form will return all the data.

If you already have some JavaSctipt variables holding your "session" data, you can simply send them as an object through the AJAX call - there is no need to serialize the data if you already have all of it in one variable.

If you are wanting to pass some server session variables then you might want to consider the following approach - 
You can save your session variable data and encode it to a json object using `json_encode()`.  After that you can pass it to your JavaScript simply by echoing it out into a variable -

```
var sess_data = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION); ?>' ;
```

Then you can just pass the variable with your AJAX call - no need to serialize the data.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "script.php",
   data: sess_data,
   success: function() {
     ...
   }
});
```

Comment: I think the OP is using the [jQuery Session Plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin#readme).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear to me if it is an array or an object or whatever, but you can probably use [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) for this.

From the docs:

> Create a serialized representation of an array or object, suitable for
>   use in a URL query string or Ajax request.

--

```
var data = $.session("data");

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "script.php",
   data: {data: $.param(data)},
   success: function() {
     ...
   }
});
```

and catch it in PHP

```
parse_str($_POST['data'], $myVariable);
```

Comment: "Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values." My session data is not form elements though.

Comment: What is the improvement with using this over `$.serialize()` in this situation? How is another question an answer?

Comment: Look a little closer and you'll see `$.session()`, which I believe is a plugin working with `sessionStorage`. I've asked in a comment below the question for clarification.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I don't really the know the plugin, so I have no idea what that function outputs, it could be anything? The question is'nt really clear on what exactly it is either. Edited my answer, and I believe it will work either way?

Comment: Well $.param should work with both an array or an object, so unless it's something else completely, that should work ?

Comment: The way I read it (and I could be wrong) is the OP wants to serialize `sessionStorage` variables like `json_encode($_SESSION)` in PHP. Maybe `sessionStorage.getItem('data')` is where what serializable data they're after. I don't know. Hence the question.